# Can't start Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, laptop, compaq, presario

I'm using a compaq presario cq60 and i'm not really able to boot through the usb drive. My dvd drive is broken, and my version of windows got corrupted, so ubuntu is my only option.

this is sort of what I see with a normal boot. Any ideas? (i'm a noob)

SQUASHFS ERROR:
ZLIB DECOMPRESSION FAILED, DATA PROBABLY CORRUPT
SQASHFS_READ_DATA FAILED TO READ BLOCK 0X25B79FE1
UNABLE TO READ FRAGMENT CACHE ENTRY 0x25b79fe1
UNABLE TO READ PAGE, BLOCK 25B79FE1, SIZE B6F2

Comment: I somehow got it to boot correctly after booting seven times, but i'm experiencing internal errors and system program problems.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the USB is corrupt. If you can get on a Windows machine and download
Linux LiveUSB creator. and follow the instructions.

Comment: Okay, i'll give that method a try, see if the results are any different.

Comment: after several restarts, i've gotten it booted however the desktop is all black and no applications are running. Error somewhere, just not sure where.

Comment: after 20 seconds it crashed, and everything is now a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having one of these problems:

1. Bad memory modules (you can use memtest86+ to check the memory).
2. A bad drive (if possible, try using a different usb drive).
3. A corrupted image (have you run an md5 checksum to verify the image?, if not then please do, and if they don't match, download the iso image again).

If the errors are still not fixed, I think you should try switching the ubuntu version, to 15.04 for example. Sometimes some versions don't work well with some particular hardware configurations. I was in trouble due to this for a long time! Good luck.

Comment: im stuck at the ubuntu loading screen now. I'm using a Lexar 32 gb flashdrive, not sure if that's compatible. I'm going to wait a few minutes on the loading screen, then i'll see about returning the usb drive, any good recommendations?

Comment: All seems good on your end. Perhaps the image is corrupt. You can try redownloading the iso image, or you may try some other version of ubuntu. Use some tool for creating the usb bootable if you're not sure how to do it manually. Some tools available are:

On windows: Win32 Disk Imager;
On Linux: Startup Disk Creator